# web.py todo list using sqlite invalid literal for int()

Tags: python, sqlite, web.py

I was following the tutorial here http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial then looked around the webs to find out how to use the todo list part with sqlite and found this http://kzar.co.uk/blog/view/web.py-tutorial-sqlite

I cannot get passed this error. I have searched and none of the results i can find help me out too much. Most are suggesting to take the quotes out of the parentheses.

Error

```
<type 'exceptions.ValueError'> at /
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '19 02:39:09'
```

code.py

```
import web

render = web.template.render('templates/')

db = web.database(dbn='sqlite', db='testdb')

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

class index:
    def GET(self):
        todos = db.select('todo')
        return render.index(todos)

if __name__ == "__main__": app.run()
```

templates/index.html

```
$def with (todos)
<ul>
$for todo in todos:
    <li id="t$todo.id">$todo.title</li>
</ul>
```

testbd

```
CREATE TABLE todo (id integer primary key, title text, created date, done boolean default 'f');
CREATE TRIGGER insert_todo_created after insert on todo
begin
update todo set created = datetime('now')
where rowid = new.rowid;
end;
```

Very new to web.py sqlite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere, `int()` is being called with the argument `'19 02:39:09'`.  `int()` can't handle colons or spaces.

```
>>> int('19 02:39:09')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    int('19 02:39:09')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '19 02:39:09'

>>> int(':')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    int(':')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ':'

>>> int('19 02 39 09')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    int('19 02 39 09')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '19 02 39 09'

>>> int('19023909')
19023909
>>>
```

I would suggest calling `replace()` to get rid of the spaces and colons like this:

```
>>> date='19 02:39:09'
>>> date=date.replace(" ","")
>>> date
'1902:39:09'
>>> date=date.replace(":","")
>>> date
'19023909'
>>> int(date)  ## It works now!
19023909
>>>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That indeed helped. I dont know how I would actually use the replace() in this case, but now that I know what was causing the issues, I replaced what time stamp sqlite was using. from 'now' to '%j'. Ill have to give it more time to figure out the right way to fix it, using your solution, but this worked for now. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  :)  And there really is no "right" way, I was merely offering a suggestion if you couldn't think of one yourself.  You are free to use whichever method works best for you.

Answer (score 1):

just change type of 'created' column to timestamp:

date format is "YYYY-MM-DD"

timestamp - "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"

this sql should work fine:

```
CREATE TABLE todo (id integer primary key, title text, created timestamp, done boolean default 'f');
CREATE TRIGGER insert_todo_created after insert on todo
begin
update todo set created = datetime('now', 'localtime')
where rowid = new.rowid;
end;
```